# OpenVPN split traffic by users

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have several users and each one has an own VM with individual virtual network interfaces on the same machine.
I want to give VPN access for each of the users so they can reach the VMs by connecting to a **main VPN server** and after that all their traffic should be redirected to their own VM's interface (without the possibility to reach others' VM).

Basically I want to split the traffic to different network interfaces by users.

I know it can be done by multiple VPN server instances (e.g. openvpn) but I prefer to have one main VPN server for the lower resource requirements and the better user management.

Can it be done with OpenVPN? (or with any other vpn servers?)

**Example:**

Users:

- *user_a*
- *user_b*

Virtual machine's tap interfaces:

- *VM-1*: 10.0.0.1
- *VM-2*: 10.0.0.2

*user_a* can connect to the vpn server hosted on the main os and all its traffic will be redirected to 10.0.0.1

*user_b* can connect to the vpn server hosted on the main os and all its traffic will be redirected to 10.0.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pfsense (firewall rule + built-in OpenVPN server). 
- You need to allocate to each user one IP : cf on the OpenVPN server there is an option in the clients settings/topology).
- you add a firewall rule for each ip (as each user has a unique IP you are effectively setuping a rule per user).

Comment: In that case, one user can only have one connection. I'm looking for a more general solution. Is there an option for reserving an IP range for each user?

Comment: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/openvpn/openvpn-configuration-options.html

Comment: as far i can see, you cannot : if a user need multiple connection then you should give him multiple vpn access one for each device.